# UWP application : Version Numbers : Revision Number

Tags: windows-store-apps, uwpapps

Why the windows store does not allow to upload the changed revision number build?
My current Store version : 2.1.1.0
I am planning to upload the version 2.1.1.1 to store but it rejects in the validation phase. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set your updated version to 2.1.2.0/2.2.1.0 or any other higher version number,as long as the last number is set as 0.

Derived from [Package version numbering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/package-version-numbering):
For Windows 10 (UWP) packages, the last (fourth) section of the version number is reserved for Store use and must be left as 0 when you build your package (although the Store may change the value in this section).